# How to take the line profile of a matplotlib 2d contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am wondering if it is possible to get the line intensity profile from a matplotlib contour plot. Ideally I would like to hover over the contour and it give me the intensity at that point and the x and y profiles through the lines, see picture.

[image]

Any ideas where to start? Can't seem to find anything.

Comment: You would start with a static plot of what you want to show, similar to [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html). You could then use a [`Cursor`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/cursor.html) and [connect an event](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) and draw the respective data in the marginal plots.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/cursor_demo_sgskip.html